# how to ravel out the edge of a texture/mask?

Tags: shader-nodes

i have this:

[image]

and want this:

[image]

i know how to do this with "normal" texture nodes:

[image]

but what if i just have the color input?

like this:

[image]

is there a way to just ravel the edges? think of a more complicated texture, not just a circle like in my example.

this is how the result should look like:

[image]

The inside should stay the same. The edges should/can be randomized. Best would be if the randomization is bigger at the edges and gets lower to the inside. But no, the form of the edge is not a circle like i have here.

Comment: Looks like that it is not possible, overwise we have easily got blur in the textures

Comment: That’s a bit sad though….

Comment: However... the color input must somehow get information on where to put the color. So there must be some kind of texture coordinate / UV information somewhere...? Is there no way to get this into the nodetree?

Comment: Dynamic paint or image texture 

Comment: Yeah sure, but the image still has to be put onto the plane in the correct orientation, so Blender uses a UV map or a generated texture coordinate. I'm just trying to get my head around how to integrate this into this node setup.

Comment: In my current use case it is dynamic paint. So I just have an attribute which is 1 or 0 on vertex points ( I guess). Or maybe a value between 0 and 1 ? I am not sure

Comment: tbh...it looks like you gave me an idea again :) there are indeed different values when using dynamic paint so i could use these differences to get those edges...! Thanks!!

Comment: but unfortunately that area is always very thin...i can't make it bigger :(  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlTho.png

Answer (score 1):

Im eyes the best solution is not to distort or add/multiply the image, but the texture coordinates.
[image]

Depending on the settings of the noise texture and its multiplier, you can keep the 'hole', but ravel its edges.
Keep in mind, if you do this with image textures, you need to set their extrapolation to clipped.
EDIT:
[image]
A more complex, but versatile setup.

Comment: ok, maybe i should have been more clear...i don't want to "noise" everything inside, but "just" the edge (with some width of course). Maybe my example picture were to simple, but if i e.g. would have a checker texture inside, i just want to ravel out the edges

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you post an image where that fails? If you are looking for ways to 'find' a hole, there is no edge detection in Cycles and I think creating one from the available nodes will be very cumbersome.

Comment: i update my question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this is what you're going for.

Comment: thank you again for your answer, which make a really nice effect, but yours is "just" working for round shape of the mask, isn't it? sorry, but i am searching hoped for a solution which can handle "any" shape, so also it should work for a rectangle or any shape....so maybe a shape of a giraffe or whatever. or didn't i understand your solution maybe....?

Comment: It works for any 'hole', you can limit the effect by increasing the multiply node's value, or if you want to preserve rectangular shapes (x,y aligned), split the channels (separate XYZ) and treat x and y individually. As I said, detecting edges isn't something you would do with Cycles shaders, but rather in Image Editing software. I am sure there are OpenGL shaders that can do it, but it would be very slow in Cycles.

Comment: ok, let's assume i have (instead of a circle) this random shape here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUyAA.jpg and i just want to randomize now the edges of this shape as you did - but keeping the overall shape. Where do i plug my image texture in?

Comment: Replace the spherical  gradient map with any mask you like. Just give it a try, it might just work.

Comment: this is the result i got from your setup: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ani19.png now because i have no idea where i should plug my image texture in, i plugged it in all three. results:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIvtU.jpg

Comment: It should replace the gradient texture node. And also use UV as input, not object.

Comment: i am still not sure whether you mean this?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/baZcS.jpg

Comment: yes, now play with the factor (multiply node), the scale of the noise and the position of the stops of the color ramps, until you find what you like. You could also subtract 0.5 before the multiply node, that should move the shape less in general.